# Buscar pedido a partir de DBEdit al presionar enter

Tags: delphi

Tengo un formulario de pedido de una distribuidora y en un DBEdit el Id del pedido.
Y quiero que al escribir un numero de idPedido y presionar Enter busque el detalle y lo muestre en la grilla de detalle:

```
procedure TPEDIDO.DBEdit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);

// al presionar enter
var
  idpedido: integer;
begin
 if Key = #13 then
  begin
// edito el idpedido actual

idpedido := StrToInt(DBEdit1.Text);

DataModule1.cdspedidos.Close;
DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Close;
DataModule1.cdspedidos.FetchParams;
DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.FetchParams;
DataModule1.cdscliactual.Close;
DataModule1.cdscliactual.FetchParams;

DataModule1.cdspedidos.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idpedido;
DataModule1.cdspedidos.Open;
DataModule1.cdscliactual.Params.ParamByName('idc').Value :=
  DataModule1.cdspedidosIdCliente.AsInteger;
DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Open;

DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idpedido;
DataModule1.cdscliactual.Open;

// busco el detalle
DataModule1.qdetp.Close;
DataModule1.qdetp.ParamByName('idp').AsInteger := StrToInt(DBEdit1.Text);
DataModule1.qdetp.ExecSQL();

DataModule1.qdetp.Open;

DataModule1.qdetp.First;

DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Open;



 end;
```

end;

cdsdetpedido contiene el detalle (es un TClientDataSet) y cdscliactual es el cliente asociado al pedido.
A su vez qdetp es un query que selecciona el detalle a partir del id pedido:

```
   select * from detallepedido left join productos on productos.IdProducto=detallepedido.IdProducto where detallepedido.IdPedido=:idp;
```

Funciona si hago Enter 2 veces! Es decir de que manera puedo borrar el contenido de la grilla y reescribirlo?
A parte de mostrar el detalle necesito mostrar el total(cantidad * precio) por cada registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No utilices un control asociado a datos para realizar una búsqueda como esta que quieres hacer. Los controles asociados a datos de la VCL tienen un comportamiento definido.

Puedes utiliza un `TEdit` *normal*, y escribir el código para buscar el pedido en su evento OnKeyPress, como lo haces ahora, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TfrmPedido.EditNumeroPedido(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  idPedido: Integer;
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    try
      idPedido := StrToInt(Trim(Edit1.Text));
    except
      on EConvertError do
      begin
        EditNumeroPedido.SelectAll;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
    if dmPedido.AbrirPedido(idPedido) then
    begin
      EditNumeroPedido.Text := dmPedido.cdsPedidoidPedido.AsString;
      //otras cosas que hacer si existe el pedido
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Pedido no encontrado!');
      Beep;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Como mi código sugiere, es mejor que tengas un método especializado en buscar/abrir el pedido, este método podría devolver un valor booleano indicando si el pedido fue encontrado.

La base para escribir ese método ya la tienes en tu código actual, puedes re-factorizarlo para conseguirlo.

Hacer rutinas que tengan tareas específicas, y separar la lógica de negocios (encontrar un pedido) de las acciones del usuario (presionar enter en un edit para recuperar un pedido, mostrar mensajes de error, etc.) te ayudará a escribir código reutilizable, lo que hará tu aplicación más fácil de mantener.

Comment: Hola jachguate.. Nuevamente gracias por tu respuesta. Entiendo tus consejos tambien. Pero aparte de comprobar si un pedido existe, que es lo que veo que tu codigo hace, yo necesito obtener el detalle osea los articulos asociados a ese pedido.

Comment: Con el codigo que puse en mi pregunta lo logro hacer.. Pero no se actualiza la grilla al hacer enter.. A su vez necesito calcular el total, precio por cantidad para cada fila del detalle.

Comment: Si no se actualiza "la grilla", sugiero que agregues a la pregunta que grilla específicamente y a que dataset esta asociada dicha grilla, y en caso de ser un clientdataset cuál es su fuente de datos.

Comment: Lo que digo en mi respuesta, lo sostengo. Solo date cuenta que para poder escribir en el DBEdit el dataset subyacente debe estar en edición... eso dificulta tener una interacción fina con el usuario, pues antes de cambiar a otro pedido, si esta editando el actual habría que preguntarle si quiere guardar los cambios, solo por poner un ejemplo.

Comment: Para el cálculo de `cantidad * precio` puedes valerte de una columna calculada, pero esa ya sería otra pregunta.

Comment: Gracias jachguate, funciono cambiando el DBedit por un TEdit